# Mysql Limit Performance

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a large table in mysql, about 1 million records.

I'm using a dynamic query with different parameters in where clause and order, so i cant use some code like `AND id > 34000 LIMIT 10`

I have index on my fields in `WHERE` and `LIMIT` and `ORDER` but index doesn't help alone.

I need a better way than `LIMIT 34000, 10`, Is there any way to slove offset delay?

I put my table schema but i just copy more usable field without any index, because i'm using dynamic queries.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `p_apartmentbuy` (
  `property_id` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `dateadd` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `sqm` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `sqmland` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `age` tinyint(2) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `price` bigint(12) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `pricemeter` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `floortotal` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `floorno` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `unittotal` smallint(4) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `unitthisfloor` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `room` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `parking` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `renovate` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `address` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `describe` varchar(500) COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `featured` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `l_location_id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `l_city_id` smallint(4) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `pf_furnished_id` tinyint(2) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`property_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_general_ci;
```

Comment: LIMIT can be fast if the query can use an index for both WHERE and ORDER BY. Could you post the query, schema (`SHOW CREATE TABLE <table>`) and `EXPLAIN <query>` output ?

Comment: Im using index on fields is in `WHERE LIMIT ORDER` clause but it doesnt help alone, And i cant post my query because its dynamic and table schema are to big :-s @arnaud576875

Comment: Post only one variant of the query, and strip the non relevant columns from the schema ;) (just need to see the columns used in WHERE and ORDER BY clauses, plus indexes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem with a table with 1 mill records wont be the `AND id > 34000 LIMIT 10` or `LIMIT 34000, 10`  that will up to the Structure and the rest of the query.  I.E, you need index, PK, FK to speed up the query, beside that an Order by probably will slow it down, make search `like '%text%'` it will make your query SLOW.  Also it's up to the table's Engine

So don't expect that changing limit 10 will make a huge difference.  There are a couple of tool that will help you to determinate a 'better' query, but not all queries works as the same so don't expect the "best solution" because it doesn't exists.

You can use Show `create table` or `Describe select ......` or `explain` to see what's going on, or use the command `benchmark` to see the approximate time of a function that you are applying to improve it

EDIT:

Some tools for MySQL
I'll recommend you to take a look to this program that will help you with this part of performance.

- Mysqlslap (it's like benchmark but you can customize more the result).
- SysBench (test CPUperformance, I/O performance, mutex contention, memory speed, database performance).
- Mysqltuner (with this you can analize general statistics, Storage engine Statistics, performance metrics).
- mk-query-profiler (perform analysis of a SQL Statement).
- mysqldumpslow (good to know witch queries are causing problems).

Comment: Im not using low performance query like `like '%text%'` but i have to use `match against` in some queries. My biggest issue  is order by several fields and offset delay when i need 200000th record

Comment: @hamidreza66 I know that you are not using like, but I mean you can't have "the best way" because there are different ways to make a query, and the response time will vary. The most important is the structure of the DATABASE and the complete query to get a 'good' performance. I name you some tools that will help to find a better solution

Answer (score 1):

MySQL is able to optimize LIMIT clauses (i.e. only scan / evaluate the rows in the range specified by LIMIT) if it is able to use only indexes to find rows matching the query.

For queries like `SELECT * FROM users WHERE active = 1 ORDER BY created_at`, adding and index on (active, created_at) is enough.

See http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/09/01/order-by-limit-performance-optimization/

Comment: I know it, but what should i do if the query is dynamic and its posible there is 1 field in where clause or 20 field!

Comment: This query is for a search form, and can return all records and there is no sort by id or any unique id, I think its bad way to use limit offset