# get data from 15th record till last in a table

Tags: mysql, limit, offset

from a table A i have taken rows from 0-15 using limit.

Now again I require all the records from 15 onwards till the last row such that I do not know the total number of rows.

How to do this?Using `offset 15` doesnt help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use both parameters for `LIMIT`.  For the second parameter, use an unusually large number that is at least larger than the number of records in the table.  [From the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html)

> LIMIT takes one or two numeric arguments...
>
> With two arguments, the first argument specifies the offset of the first row to return, and the second specifies the maximum number of rows to return. The offset of the initial row is 0 (not 1):
>
> SELECT * FROM tbl LIMIT 5,10;  # Retrieve rows 6-15
>
> To retrieve all rows from a certain offset up to the end of the result set, you can use some large number for the second parameter. This statement retrieves all rows from the 96th row to the last:
>
> SELECT * FROM tbl LIMIT 95,18446744073709551615;

Comment: Yeah this can be done but does this large number ever effect the query execution time? Is this the best way out?

Comment: @Bhumi Singhal: There's an answer for that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11348922/mysql-limit-performance